# Why do I need to use ReactJS state to update UI after AJAX in the following scenario

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's get right to the code to demonstrate:

```js
function App() {
  let message = '!!message init value, this should not be displayed!!';
  const busyState = React.useState(true);
  let isBusy = busyState[0];
  let setIsBusy = busyState[1];
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    log('didMount');
    getLatestMessage();
  }, []);
  
  function log(message) {
    document.getElementById('console').innerText = message;
  }
  
  function getLatestMessage() {
     log('getting latest message...');
     setTimeout(() => {
      log('http call complete, there was a message for you');
      message = 'Hello World'
      setIsBusy(false);
     }, 3000);
  }
  
  return (
        <div>
        { 
        
          isBusy ? 
          <h4>
            Busy Getting Data
          </h4> :
          <h4>
            {message}
          </h4>
          
        }
      </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<label>Console:</label>
<h4 id="console" style="color: red">
</h4>
```

I am using state here. I am using the isBusy state variable to cause another render of my component. But `message` remains it's initialized value. I know I could use the `useState` hook for the message variable as well to fixed this but I thought the isBusy state flag would be enough to "flush" the old ReactJS functional component UI...?

Comment: A rerender of a functional component causes your function to get executed again. When your function is executed again, the value of the locally scoped `message` variable is (re)set to it's initial value, it has no concept of what the variable was during the last time the function was executed, get it? This is why `useState` is a thing and we don't just declare our state as locale variables in functional components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime a re-render is triggered your Functional Component, which is just a function, is called. The value of the variable "message" is set to it's "initial value" on every render in the top line of your function definition. So the value will never change. To persist state during multiple render-cycles you need to use state.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a re-render if you add the `isBusy` variable as a dependency to your `useEffect()` hook.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    getLatestMessage();
  }, [isBusy]);
```

Whenever dependiences change in `useEffect()`, it will trigger a re-render. Using an empty array causes it to only fire on initial render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am going to disagree here that your current solution is a fix, and in fact, if you watch the isBusy side effect in my code snippet it will cause an infinite rendering loop, because getLatestMessage changes the state of isBusy. In addition, even if there was not an infinite loop this still would not change the value of message :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Message needs to be a reference.

```
const message = useRef('initial value');

...
  message.current = 'Hello World'
...

<h4>
  {message.current}
</h4>
```

EDIT:
Just hoist you message variable outside of app()
(Move it up a few lines, outside of the component)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do think state for the message is more appropriate than a reference. Good point about hoisting the variable, but also not an appropriate fix IMO